# Play With String of Label /Button

Tags: c#, winforms

Suppose if my form has button and  label and Button1 has Text Property’s Text is **“Hello”** Than If I wants to make some character of **“Hello”** text in Bold,Underline  and size increment  than How to do it as below?.

**Example of Button1 string/text**

```
Normal                     Put some Efforts on
----------------------------------------------------

Hello                          “HEllo” Or “HeLlo”
```

Actually Here i unable to demonstrate well but trying to explain in words that the above **"Hello"** words available on **Put some Efforts on** Columns. If I wants **"E" Bold and underline or "L" on Bold or increment in size out from "Hello" words than how to do it?.**

I have to perform this task on both button and label.

Comment: `winforms` or `wpf` tag will be more informative than `visual-studio`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard Label and Button controls doesn't have any support for styling part of the text. What you would have to do is to create your own control that inherts the Label or Button control. Your control would put an empty string in the `Text` property so that the original would only pant the background of the control, and hook into the Paint event so that it could draw the text itself after the background was drawn.

Comment: What you think about "Regular Expression" is it not possible by Regular Expression?.

Comment: @mahesh: No. It doesn't matter what you do to the string that you put in the `Text` property, the controls are not capable of formatting the text.